# ValueError: If the `request` argument is set, then none of the individual field arguments should be set

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am using Google NLP API for Sentiment Analysis to extract sentiment score of dataframe with `review` as my text column. My code looks lik,

```
def getSentiments(df):
inserts = 0
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Content', 'Sentiment', 'Magnitude', 'ReviewId'])
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(index)
    text1 = row['review']
    reviewid = row['review_id']
    texts = []
    sentiments = []    
    magnitudes = []
    salience = []
    try:
        document = analyze_sentiment(text1)
        result = client.analyze_sentiment(document, encoding_type = "UTF8")
        # Get overall sentiment of the input document
        print(u"Document sentiment score: {}".format(result.document_sentiment.score))
       
        sentiments.append(result.document_sentiment.score)
        magnitudes.append(result.document_sentiment.magnitude)
        dfEntitySentiment = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Content','Sentiment','Magnitude', 'ReviewId'])
        dfEntitySentiment['Content'] = text1
        dfEntitySentiment['Sentiment'] = sentiments
        dfEntitySentiment['Magnitude'] = magnitudes
        dfEntitySentiment['ReviewId'] = reviewid
        df1 = df1.append(dfEntitySentiment, ignore_index = True)
        
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        continue
return df1
```

My `analyze_sentiment` function looks like,

```
def analyze_sentiment(text_content):
client = language_v1.LanguageServiceClient.from_service_account_json(Alteryx.read("#2").iloc[0]['FullPath'])
type_ = language_v1.types.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT
language = "en"
document = {"content": text_content, "type": type_, "language": language}
encoding_type = "UTF8"

return document
```

I am getting the above error and am not sure how to resolve this.

```
from google.cloud.language_v1 import enums
from google.cloud.language_v1 import types
```

These 2 libraries I was using before but I had to update them. After updating the libraries I am getting the error.

Comment: do you mind providing the full stacktrace for the error? would be helpful in seeing where the error is occurring within the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a library update, according to the [Migration Guide](https://googleapis.dev/python/language/latest/UPGRADING.html#enums-and-types), the submodule `enums` and `types` have been removed.

`request` parameter to `client.analyze_sentiment` needs to be following format,

```
result = client.analyze_sentiment(request = {'document': document, 'encoding_type': encoding_type})
```

This helped me to resolve my error.

Comment: You  may accept your posted answer so that the community knows that this has resolved your issue/concern.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully replicated your use case with the same error message.
[image]

The **error** comes from the line of code:

```py
result = client.analyze_sentiment(document, encoding_type = "UTF8")
```

To resolve this, you must explicitly assign the `document` to the individual field argument `document` for the **sentiment analysis request** as shown below:

```py
result = client.analyze_sentiment(document = document, encoding_type = "UTF8")
```

Below is the result of my sample **Sentiment Analysis request** result using the corrected line of code.

[image]

You may refer to this [AnalyzeSentimentRequest](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.language.v1#analyzesentimentrequest) reference documentation for more information regarding individual field arguments for **Google Cloud Natural Language API**.